# Can`t launch anaconda3 on ubuntu

Tags: 22.04, anaconda

I`m just trying to launch anaconda with command anaconda-navigator and terminal printing out this:

```
matviiuk@matviiuk-desktop:/media/matviiuk/DiskD/WorkPrograms/anaconda3/bin$ anaconda-navigator
2023-03-12 20:27:26,385 - WARNING linux_scaling.get_scaling_factor_using_dbus:44
Can't detect system scaling factor settings for primary monitor.

Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

I cant find information how to fix it in. Everywhere just simply advices about reinstalling or updating anaconda or it`s part, that I have already made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This look like an error with the Qt platform plugin not being started properly.

You can try to install the `libxcb-xinerama0` package which give `xcb` platform plugin, then set the QT_QPA_PLATFORM env variable with this `export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb` then you can try launching again with this `anaconda-navigator -platform xcb`

If this doesnt work try updating your graphic drivers and again try reinstalling the latest version of anaconda from the official website and follow their instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue while running Anaconda on my Ubuntu system. After spending some time on the internet, I found out that the solution was lying in the version of `pyqt5` being used.
I re-installed a slightly downgraded version of `pyqt5` using `pip`:

```
pip install pyqt5==5.14.2
```

and also `pyqtwebengine` using `pip`:

```
pip install pyqtwebengine==5.14
```

Now, it is working fine. I don't know the exact reason why I need to downgrade the `pyqt5` in order to make it work, though.